# how to add column dynamically in datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

how to add column dynamically in datagridview using c#

Answer (score 12):

For example:

```
        DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = "Hi there";
        int colIndex = grid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: I get 'DataGridViewColumn' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Answer (score 2):

If it's like any of the other .Net grid controls:

```
YourDataGridView.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewColumn());
```

Comment: Columns.Add can throw an exception if the CellType property of your DataGridViewColumn is null.  I believe it's better to set the DataGridViewColumn's CellTemplate before adding it (CellType is the runtime type of CellTemplate), or to use a class that inherits from DataGridViewColumn for which CellTemplate is already set appropriately.

Comment: @Tim Goodman - I'd agree, my example is just to show basically how it can be done. An actual implementation would be a bit more involved.

Answer (score 1):

I you mean to add all value on particular column then maybe it could help you.

Try this tips:

```
for (int i=0; i< datagriview1.coulums.count -1; i++)
{
  int total + = total + datagridview1.columns[i]
    .cell[index for columns you want to add].formatedvalue.toString();  

}

textbox1.text=total;
```

Try that code. it can help you.

Thanks,
Nico

Answer (score 0):

I am also tested this code you mean to add all value on particular column then maybe it could help you.
Try this tips:

```
gridView1.Columns.Clear();
gridView1.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() {Caption = @"Caption", FieldName = "FieldName", Name = "FieldName", Visible = true});
```