# How do i add more cells to a column of datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: DataGridView]

Now i have one cell i added it in the designer but if i want to add more cells in my code ?

I tried in the constructor to do:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

But getting exception on:

```
row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
```

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377400/how-to-add-column-dynamically-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should get an exception. Look at your code below. With `row.Cells[1]` you are actually referring to 2nd column in your gridview which apparently doesn't exists and so the end result.

```
 row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
```

If you want to have another column to your grid then either add that using your designer surface (OR) create a `DataTable` with required columns and set that to `DataSource` of your gridview.

*How to create a DataTable and attach it to GridView?*

Search [*Google*](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How+to+create+a+DataTable+and+attach+it+to+GridView%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3Z6FVpm3LsGcugTlia-YAw)

**EDIT:**

In case you are still struggling understanding my comment then this is what I meant to say (sample code)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Message Subject");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[dc] = "test";

        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[dc] = "test123";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: I guess it's my mistake. I want to add a cell to existing column with my code it's adding text to the first cell.

Comment: @HaimShabort, No that's not the way. Create a DataTable and fill it with data and then attach that datatable to your gridview. Check the link in answer to get lots of example.

Comment: @HaimShabort, see edit in answer if that helps at all.