# C#: How can I show a 1D array and a 2D array in datagridview?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, datagridview

I have a 1-D array: array_1[90] and a 2-D array: array_2[90,90]. I don't know how can make a loop to show both of them in DataGridView?

Is it better if I combine the array 1 and array 2 => a new 2-D array then show it on datagridview?

I'm new to C#, so please give me a sample sample loop displaying data in gridview.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to show either of them? Take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633018/show-2d-array-in-datagridview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377400/how-to-add-column-dynamically-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp.

Comment: Is your 1-D array 90 rows with 1 column or 90 columns with 1 row?

Comment: It's 90 rows in a column